# How do I access the input from UITextView in Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have linked my UITextView and I have looked all around and could not seem to be able to access the information my user inputs. This probably is a dumb question but I am Kinda new to swift so any advice would be awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: consider searching first then ask question... http://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618623-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you are looking for the content of the UITextView. In that case, you can access the content by:

```
textView.text
```

The above example would be if you have a UITextView named textView:

```
var textView = UITextView()
```